# Ruby return value in the if loop and code clarification

Tags: ruby

Here is the [Digit fifth powers](https://projecteuler.net/problem=30)
I did not get why my "ans" is zero since the each_sum should has its value and added up in the

```
ans  = ans  + each_sum
```

and there is a number matched in the

```
i == i.to_s.each_char{|c| each_sum = each_sum + c.to_i**5 }
```

Code

```
def digit_fifth_powers
    max = 0 
    4.times {max = max + 9**5}    #max = 236196
    each_sum,ans = 0,0
    (2..max).each do |i|
        if i == i.to_s.each_char{|c| each_sum = each_sum + c.to_i**5 }
            ans  = ans  + each_sum 
        end
    end 
    ans
end 

p digit_fifth_powers
```

ans is 0

Comment: Why so complicated way of calculating the max? Why the loop and series of additions? Can't you just do the multiplication directly, `4 * 9 ** 5`? And btw, the actual theoretical limit seems to be `5 * 9 ** 5`.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Thank you! I did not notice that.

Answer (score 1):

Okay. I check it twice, my previous answer was incorrect.

The point is `i` is Fixnum and that long statement returns String, hence the false in condition. Make it `i.to_s == ...`

Comment: i.to_s.each_char{|c| each_sum = each_sum + c.to_i**5 }, this method wont return the value of "each_sum"??

Comment: @paulsus: of course not. Read documentation on `each_char`.